# Using animateWithDuration to fade subview makes parent(ViewController) fade as well

Tags: ios, swift

so I'm trying to fade in a custom control and fade out a UIButton. The fading of the custom control is all well, but when I try to fade out the UIButton the whole screen goes black, which is due to the alpha of the root view being set to 0. Here's the code:

```
func fadeKeypadIn() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.keypad.alpha = 1
        self.btnVideo.alpha = 0

        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.btnKeypad.alpha = 0
        self.view.alpha = 1
        }, completion: {(value: Bool) -> Void in
            self.view.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

In the above code if I don't do `self.view.alpha = 1` the screen remains totally black.

And here's what the code does in action:

[FadeInOutProblem](https://youtu.be/0OTIWziujJk)

I'm using Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

Comment: how does self.view.alpha get set to 0 in the first place?

Comment: That's a very good question :-D

Comment: Is `self.btnVideo == self.view`?

Comment: yes it was. I don't have any frigging idea how it was set to that, but recreating the outlets fixed it. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how on earth this happened, but the outlets to the buttons I wanted to fade out were referring to the parent view. :|

Recreating the outlets CAREFULLY solved the problem.

Comment: I've missed before when dragging to connect outlets. It makes for strange bugs, because you assume they are either not connected or connected to the correct thing. Most recently, I had an app that requested an online application. Below that was a test button that erased all the saved data. Apparently when I was connecting the erase action I missed and connected that code to the apply button. The apply button had both the apply action AND the erase action, so clicking apply erased your old info before applying again. Drove me crazy figuring out what was wrong.

Comment: Man that's NOT pleasant :-D. Specially if you're on an insane deadline, like me